# Change the style of moving to next activity in phonegap - mobile android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using phonegap for my application.When I move from one activity to another, by default the first one dissappears and the next activity appears. I want to change it so that when I move from one activity to another, the first one goes into left and the next one enters the screen from right. Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

1. If the page change is NOT triggered by Javascript, and you want to configure for that transition *specifically*, then you can add `data-transition="slide"` to the `a` tag that triggers such transition.
2. If the page change is triggered by Javascript, and you want to configure for that transition *specifically*, then you can add the option `transition: "slide"` to the JS Object passed to `changePage()` function:

   ```
   $.mobile.changePage("#destPage", {
     // Other options
     transition: "slide"
   });
   ```
3. If you want to change the default behavior of the transition (global change), then you can run the code below ***before*** the inclusion of jQuery Mobile script:

   ```
   $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
     $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
     // Other overrides
   });
   ```

   For this last method, you can take a look at the documentation of [configuring the default settings of jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html) for more details.

Check out [other transitions](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html) that you can have with jQuery Mobile. The page also mentions the first method of transition, which can be used with `a` tag (link) or form submission.

Comment: thanks friend, I am using window.location to change the screen. Is it possible to use some way there?

Comment: @harsh: I'm not sure, but I think you should change your code to use jQuery mobile method of page transitioning (2nd method).

Comment: I have not used jQuery mobile before. I will try this and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @harsh: Ah, sorry. Didn't read the question carefully. Thought you have been using jQuery Mobile already. But I think my answer still has  value, since it's better to use library to cut down the styling jobs.